# python 3.5 installation on window 7 - 64 bit [compatability issue]

Tags: python-3.x, installation

Current version python 2.7.10 32 BIT is installed on my system.Yes, 32 Bit version is working correctly.

```
>python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

My Processor and operating system details are as follow:

```
Processor   : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU@4.00GHz
System Type : 64 bit Operating System
```

I'm trying to download correct version for my system from this link.
[https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/]

I go to link --> Latest Python 3 Release - Python 3.5.0
After this i have 2 option

1) Windows x86-64 web-based installer -for AMD64/EM64T/x64, not Itanium processors

2) Windows x86 web-based installer

Both of these version of Python are giving me incompatibility issues.
Please suggest how to diagnose or point out the correct version for my system.

Answer (score 0):

I found the 64-bit installer on FileHorse. Just be sure you change the path to C:/Python35 or is installs it on your Users folder. I use the i7-4771 processor and run this version just fine.